# Need to float list items left to avoid margin, but want it centered in the page

Tags: css, menu, css-float, inline

What I would like to happen is to have a menu of list items that are centered in the page.  I displayed them as inline, had it centered and it looked great.  But when I added decoration to the a:hover, I noticed there were about 3px of margin between the items.  I had margin and padding set to 0 on everything in the list and list items.  I found out that this is an auto margin of sorts from it being inline (inline-block).  The suggestions I had seen were to leave it as inline and either do this:

```
<li>ListItem1</li><li>ListItem2</li>...
```

or

```
<li>ListItem1</li><li>
ListItem2</li><li>
ListItem3</li>...
```

However, it's not the best for reading in either scenario.  Is there any way that I can float my list items so that there is no margin between them, but have the menu centered in the page.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="iccmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">H o m e</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">F o r u m s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C h a t</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C o l l e c t i o n s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T r a d e</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">M e s s a g e s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">H e l p</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS.

```
#iccmenu
{
    text-align:center;
}

#iccmenu ul
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#iccmenu ul li
{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    border:0;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#iccmenu ul li:first-child
{
    border-left:0;
}

#iccmenu a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:orange;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px grey;
    padding:7px 25px;
    margin:0;
}

#iccmenu a:hover
{
    background-color:grey;
    text-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same code you're using, if you want to keep them centered, try this on `#iccmenu ul`

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LepD9/

Comment: Much appreciated.  I completely forgot about auto for a second.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i will add use this:

```
#iccmenu ul
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    min-width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

so it doesnt break when the page is smaller than needed **min-width**

and u can fix the hover effect by adding line-height with the same value as the height of the link [My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ic0o09988/VpqBJ/):

```
#iccmenu a{   
 line-height:34px;
}
```